# Linux/Apache 2.2.6 ServerTokens Full change to ServerTokens Prod

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, web-server

Noob questions im guessing but im trying to find where to change "ServerTokens Full" to "ServerTokens Prod" but I cannot seem to find it. im in the apache/apache2.conf. Along with this I want to turn off ServerSignature any help with an explanation would be great.

I am just getting into this web servers and programming in general and am finding it pretty awesome.

Comment: *One sure way to stop being a noob is to read documentation*

Answer (score 2):

The default value for [servertokens](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#servertokens) is Full this probably why you can't find it anywhere to change it. As you can see from the linked servertokens documentation the [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) is `server config`. The main Apache server configuration on ubuntu is found in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` so adding

```
ServerTokens Prod
```

to it and restarting Apache should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apache.org regarding [ServerTokens](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servertokens):

> Setting ServerTokens to less than minimal is **not recommended** because
>   it makes it more difficult to debug interoperational problems. Also
>   note that disabling the Server: header does nothing at all to make
>   your server more secure; the idea of *"security through obscurity"* is a
>   myth and leads to a false sense of safety.